# Regression in R using vectorization and matrices

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, vectorization, regression

I have a vectorization Q in R using matrices. I have 2 Cols that need to be regressed against each using certain indices.  Data is

```
matrix_senttoR = [ ...
                  0.11 0.95
                  0.23 0.34
                  0.67 0.54
                  0.65 0.95
                  0.12 0.54
                  0.45 0.43 ] ;
indices_forR = [ ...
            1
            1
            1
            2
            2
            2 ] ;
```

Col1 in matrix is data for say MSFT and GOOG (3 rows each) and Col2 is the return from benchmark StkIndex, on corresponding dates.  The data is in matrix format as it is sent from Matlab.

I currently use

```
slope <- by(    data.frame(matrix_senttoR),   indices_forR,   FUN=function(x)  
                         {zyp.sen (X1~X2,data=x) $coeff[2] }      ) 
betasFac <- sapply(slope , function(x) x+0)
```

I'm using data.frame above as I could not use cbind().  If I use cbind() then Matlab gives an error as it doesn't understand that format of data.  I'm running these commands from inside Matlab (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5051).  You can replace `zyp` (zyp.sen) with `lm`.

`BY` is slow here (may be because of dataframes?).  Is there a better way to do it?  It takes 14secs+ for 150k rows of data.  Can I instead use matrix-vectorization in R? Thanks.

Comment: If you are just running a regression, why bother passing the code from MATLAB to R?  MATLAB's `regress` function in the Stats toolbox will do the trick.

Comment: It is also a good idea to do some profiling on the code to see where the slowdown lies. You need to know how much time is taken up with `by` and how much with your modelling function, and how much time is spent passing data between MATLAB and R.

Comment: @Richie -> It is because I'm trying to do non-parametric regression, specifically using zyp library package.  All my data is in Matlab.  My only option is to design the Theil-Sen Regressor in Matlab myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think that you are overcomplicating things by moving from MATLAB to R and back.  And passing 150k rows of data must be slowing things down considerably.

`zyp.sen` is actually pretty trivial to port to MATLAB.  Here you go:

```
function [intercept, slope, intercepts, slopes, rank, residuals] = ZypSen(x, y)
% Computes a Thiel-Sen estimate of slope for a vector of data.

n = length(x);

slopes = arrayfun(@(i) ZypSlopediff(i, x, y, n), 1:(n - 1), ...
    'UniformOutput', false);
slopes =  [slopes{:}];
sni = isfinite(slopes);
slope = median(slopes(sni));

intercepts = y - slope * x;
intercept = median(intercepts);

rank = 2;
residuals = x - slope * y + intercept;

end


function z = ZypSlopediff(i, x, y, n)

z = (y(1:(n - i)) - y((i + 1):n)) ./ ...
    (x(1:(n - i)) - x((i + 1):n));

end
```

I checked this using the R's `example(zyp.sen)`, and it gives the same answer.

```
x = [0 1 2 4 5]
y = [6 4 1 8 7]
[int, sl, ints, sls, ra, res] = ZypSen(x, y)
```

You should really do some further checking though, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This could easily be moved to a comment, but:

A few things to consider, I tend to avoid the `by()` function since its return value is a funky object.  Instead, why not add your indices_forR vector to the data.frame?

```
df <- data.frame(matrix_senttoR) 
df$indices_forR <- indices_forR
```

the plyr package does the work from here:

```
ddply(df,.(indices_forR),function(x) zyp.sen(X1~X2,data=x)$coeff[2])
```

you can easily [multi-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775098/r-with-a-multi-core-processor) this operation using doMC or doSnow and the argument `.parallel=TRUE` to ddply.

if speed is the goal, I would also learn the [data.table](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-timings.pdf&ei=vqMdT5zzAc3WiALrrpyaCA&usg=AFQjCNEgW8OGVG1sJVfhQ4av1I3TWV_o_Q) package (which wraps data.frame and is much faster).  Also, I assume that the slow piece is the `zyp.sen()` call rather than the `by()` call.  Executing on multiple cores will speed this along.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(X1 = c(0.11, 0.23, 0.67, 0.65, 0.12, 0.45), X2 = c(0.95, 
0.34, 0.54, 0.95, 0.54, 0.43), indices_forR = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "indices_forR"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

> ddply(df,.(indices),function(x) lm(X1~X2,data=x)$coeff[2])
  indices         X2
1       1 -0.3702172
2       2  0.6324900
```

Comment: -> the step ddply does not work when implemented like
evalR('slope <- ddply(df,.(indices_forR),function(x) zyp.sen(X1~X2,data=x)$coeff[2])') ;  I get an error: Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception: Object is static; operation not allowed

Comment: @Maddy that sounds like a Matlab error rather than an R error.  not sure which package `zyp.sen()` comes from but using `lm()` in R itself it works great.

Comment: -> Thanks Justin.  But I guess im stuck with zyp for now.  It is non-parametric and I have to use it specifically.  I knew that it is matlab based error.  Im not really well versed with R and so had put this Q hoping for a solution.