# Using multiple cores to run latin hypercube sampling in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, sampling

I am intending to extract representative samples from populations (a,b,c,d,... see below) using the "clhs" package in R. The sampling process takes very long on my (multicore) computer, so I'd like to run the sampling procedures in parallel (using multiple CPU cores simultaneously).

These are some of my (example) data frames ("populations") from which I want to draw the samples:

```
a <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
b <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
c <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
d <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
```

The clhs code I want to run is:

```
clh_a <- clhs(x=a, size=round(nrow(a)/5), iter=2000, simple=F)) # 20% of all samples should be selected
clh_b <- clhs(x=b, size=round(nrow(b)/5), iter=2000, simple=F))
```

etc...

What is the way to run this sampling process in parallel? Or is there another way of doing this in an efficient manner?

**Addendum (many thanks to "zipfzapf"):**

I was trying to use "parLapply" - unfortunately, at the end, R is throwing an error message saying: "Error in length(x): 'x' is missing", which I honestly don't understand... Any ideas?

My code:

```
    library("snow")
            a <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
            b <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
            c <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
    d <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
    abcd <- list(a, b, c, d)
    cl <- makeCluster(4)
    results <- parLapply(cl,
       X = abcd,
       FUN = function(i) {
         clhs(x = i, size = round(nrow(i) / 5), iter = 2000, simple = FALSE)
       },
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me (notice I changed the number of iterations to make things move along at a reasonable pace).

```
library(snowfall)
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 4, type = "SOCK")
sfLibrary(clhs)

x <- sfLapply(abcd, fun = function(x) {
            clhs(x = x, size=round(nrow(x)/5), iter = 200, simple =FALSE)
        })

     Length Class       Mode
[1,] 5      cLHS_result list
[2,] 5      cLHS_result list
[3,] 5      cLHS_result list
[4,] 5      cLHS_result list
```

Comment: Indeed your solution using "sfLapply" seems to work well! I just observed strange system.time values, which is probably due to the parallel mode...? Anyway, many thanks, this saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

The function `mclapply` from the (builtin) package `parallel` is a multi-core version of `lapply`:

```
library(parallel)

# population samples
abcd <- list(a, b, c, d)

# multi-core version of 'lapply(abcd, [....])'
results <- parallel::mclapply(
  X = abcd,
  FUN = function(elem) {
    clhs(x = elem, size = round(nrow(elem) / 5), iter = 2000, simple = FALSE))
  },
  mc.preschedule = FALSE,
  mc.cores = 4L
)
```

This will give you a list where each element contains the result of the corresponding `clhs` call.

Note that arguments `mc.preschedule` and `mc.cores` are optional. Setting `mc.preschedule` to `FALSE` is a good idea if each function call of `FUN` may take a while (as in your case).

Comment: Many thanks! This solution looks indeed very elegant! Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that I'm using R(2.15.2) on Win7 (64b) - I guess this is why R is telling me: "Error in parallel::mclapply(X = abcd, FUN = function(elem) {:'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows". Is there an equivalent package for Windows?

Comment: You might check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775098/r-with-a-multi-core-processor). It seems that the [package 'snow'](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html) provides functions (_e.g._ `parLapply`) that work in a similar manner as above for Windows settings

Comment: @Chega You could use `snowfall` that is sort of like `snow`.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik - Thanks for this - I was adding an addendum to my original question, where I describe an issue with "parLapply". I was trying snowfall as well - same problem! Can't figure out what is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

A solution using "snow" - simply adding "clusterEvalQ(cl, library(clhs))" did the trick:

```
a <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
b <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
c <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
d <- as.data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(20)))
abcd <- list(a, b, c, d)
library("snow")
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(clhs))
results <- parLapply(cl, abcd, fun = function(elem) {
    clhs(x = elem, size = round(nrow(elem) / 2), iter = 50)
  })
stopCluster(cl)
```

Many thanks again to zipfzapf & Roman Luštrik!