# Utilizing multiple cores in R

Tags: r

I recently found that R by default runs on a single processor even if my system has multi-cores. If I want to decrease my processing time, I have to utilize all 8 cores but I am not sure how to do this. I did try using the function from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775098/r-package-that-automatically-uses-several-cores), but it didn't help.
Does anyone know how to give a global command to R to utilize all cores by default? Or any other solutions to the same problem ?

Comment: "Does anyone know how to give a global command to R studio to utilize all cores by default?" Such a command currently does not exist. There are some packages that offer (limited) parallelization for specific tasks by default but it is generally necessary to use one of the [parallelization frameworks (available as packages)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) explicitly for the task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this, but it won't help you much if you have a sequential algorithm.

```
library(parallel)
detectCores() # returns 1,2,4,8 or whatever

# Create cluster via makeCluster
cl <- makeCluster(8)

# you can do a parallel matrix operation, apply() like this.
# here, calculate column medians
parApply(cl, mymatrix, 2, median)

#  run 100 iterations in parallel 
# with  a parallel sapply() like this
res <- parSapply(cl, 1:100, function(x) myfunction(x))

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: what is mymatrix here ? I want to use this for faster 'for loop' execution

Comment: some matrix consisting only of numerical data. `apply()` only works with matrices and arrays.

Comment: will this work for a for loop ?